NextJS showing CredentialsSignIn error although the input email and passwords are valid
Hi my project is still at developing and I am testing whether user can sign-in or not.
My code -
//routes.ts
/**
 * An array of route that are assessible for public. These routes do not require authentication.
 */
export const publicRoutes = ["/"];

/**
 * An array of route that are used for authentication. These routes will redirect loggin users to /settings.
 */
export const authRoutes = ["/auth/login", "/auth/register"];

/**
 * The prefix for API authentication routes. Routes that start with this prefix are used for API authentication purposes.
 */

export const apiAuthPrefix = "/api/auth";

/**
 * The default redirect path after logging in.
 */
export const DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT = "/settings";

//middleware.ts
import authConfig from "../auth.config";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import {
  DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
  publicRoutes,
  authRoutes,
  apiAuthPrefix,
} from "../routes";

const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);

export default auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;

  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isAuthRoutes = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

  if (isApiAuthRoute) {
    return undefined;
  }

  if (isAuthRoutes) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl));
    }
    return undefined;
  }

  if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL("/auth/login", nextUrl));
  }
  return undefined;
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)",

    "/(api|trpc)(.*)",
  ],
};

//auth.ts
`import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import authConfig from "./auth.config";

export const { auth, handlers, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  ...authConfig,
});`

//login.ts
"use server";

import * as z from "zod";
import { LoginSchema } from "../schemas";
import { signIn } from "../auth";
import { DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT } from "../routes";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";

export const login = async (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
  const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(values);

  if (!validatedFields.success) {
    return {
      error: "Invalid fields",
    };
  }

  const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;

  try {
    await signIn("credentials", {
      email,
      password,
      redirectTo: DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case "CredentialsSignin":
          return { error: "Invalide Credentials!" };
        default:
          return { error: "Something went wrong!" };
      }
    }
    throw error;
  }
};


My errors although I test with valid email and password:
Invalide Credentials! (AT UI COMPONENT)
[auth][error] CredentialsSignin: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#credentialssignin
    at Module.callback (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:230:23)   
    at async AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:66:24)
    at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:126:34)
    at async signIn (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:51:17)
    at async $$ACTION_0 (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./actions/login.ts:30:9)
    at async D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:418
    at async rw (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:7978)
    at async r6 (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:41:1256)
    at async doRender (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1438:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1599:28) 
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1931:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1969:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
    at async D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
    at async invokeRender (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (D:\Projects\for-her\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13)

I tried to import signIn from
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
I tried to import AuthErrors from import { AuthError } from "@auth/core/errors";
I checked all the code but found nothing wrong.

Having the same issue suddenly. Tried with several accounts. My calls are getting to my server actions but failing in the signIn method
